# Hide/Show a View dragged above tableviewcell in Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a `tableView`, from storyboard i have dragged a `UIView` just above cell within `tableView`.So i want to `Hide/Show` that view on button Action which is outside tableView. Another thing is when i hide that view on button Action `tableView` will scroll Up and when i show that view on button Action tableView will scroll down,Anyhelp will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you written? Please read [Ask]

Comment: @AshleyMills problem is already resolved so why u r down voting me

Answer (score 0):

That can be done via two ways. 
i) Either you can create a **protocol** in uitableviewCell class and implement in MasterClas which is having your tableview.

ii) Or you can directly call a function which will hide/show your view in MasterClass(Which is having your tableview) in cell for row at index. Like below

`cell.button.addTarget(self, : "MasterClassFunction:", forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)`

Both function will work. And for top and down animation. Just calculate your view's height and change Y axis as per your requirement On function call with a animation block. 
Hope this will help.

Okay here i am editing my answer for some code reference.

`protocol tableViewCellDelegate {
    func buttonAction()

}

@IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!

in awakefrom nib :

`cell.button.addTarget(self, : "buttonActionCell:", forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)

func buttonActionCell(){

delegate.buttonAction()
}

And in your masterClass assign delegate to controller's reference and call the protocol function in your main class

func buttonAction(){

print("Func called in class file")
}

`

Comment: could u tell me how @Ballu

Comment: i have dragged a view just above tableviewcell so that it will work as a header @Ballu can u tell me

Comment: view is not in the cell

Comment: Please see my comments above. In this i used the Approach 1st. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes using this approach you can call any function which is outside of cell class. You just need to implement protocol which is created in cell class.

Comment: checking and let u know

Comment: bro i am not showing that view in xib only dragged above tableviewcell @Ballu

Comment: This is just a reference you can use this to implement whole logic. But hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: could u post code as per my req. it will he helpful @Ballu

Comment: Try this gist. Take example for your reference. https://gist.github.com/austinzheng/db58036c4eb825e63e88 you can understand this sample and do your work.

Comment: will check @ballu

Comment: could u tell me how can i create a tableview programmatically just below textfield @Ballu

Comment: Please do the google for that or take some tutorial for reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153777/discussion-between-anuj-and-ballu).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an outlet for the height of the UIView that you want to hide. give the vertical spacing of the tableview to zero with that UIView.
Then on the Button action you need to give the code for the height constraint of the UIView to be set to zero.